# Can I run python code in flutter application?

Tags: python, flutter, machine-learning, speech-recognition, spectrogram

I want my flutter application to use .tflite model to classify audio recordings. However my model input is spectrograms (not audio files). Is there a way I can run python function that converts audio to spectrogram on flutter?

I tried using starflut package but it didn't work.